# How to run angularjs code in visualforce

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a quiz engine in my organisation and I found an open source code (angularjs) that fulfill my requirements, ([you can find the project here](https://github.com/softgandhi/ngQuiz)) ([a live demo here](http://anuraggandhi.com/ngquiz/index.html#/home)) so naturally I would like to integrate it directly in my visualforce page but it does not work, **it shows me a blank page**.

Here is my visual force page ( actually, I have modified the index.html file to include all the other files as static resources ). Are there any other modifications to do for the other files (knowing that I have worked with angularjs before)?

```
  <apex:page showHeader="false">
  <html ng-app="appNameHere">
    <head>

    <!-- You may wish to bundle and minify in your project. It is not bundled and minified here to keep things simple here. -->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cssAngular, 'css/style.css')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"/>

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/app.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/helperService.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/quizCtrl.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/createCtrl.js')}"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ng-view"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where you initialized angular app? [Init angular app](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: In the original file it is initialized in html tag, and i do not know how to initialize it in the visualforce page '<html ng-app="quizApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
  <html ng-app="quizApp">
    <head>

    <!-- You may wish to bundle and minify in your project. It is not bundled and minified here to keep things simple here. -->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cssAngular, 'css/style.css')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"/>

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/app.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/helperService.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/quizCtrl.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'app/createCtrl.js')}"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ng-view"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes, i tried that and i get an error in my firebug console, i have updated the question to include the error message

Comment: Replace `ng-app="appNameGoesHere"` with `ng-app="quizApp"`; Here app name is the problem; see updated answer;

Comment: sorry for taking too long to give you a feedback,( i had a connexion problem), this time i have another problem 'Error: The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.' the raison is the link of the visualforce page that i get after executing the above code "**/apex/QuizAngular#/home". i do not know why the "#"  is here i tried to search the code but i did not find any redirection links. i t should be a angularjs trick

Comment: if you are running into other errors, please consider asking a new question as specified in [ask] . Thanks