# change AngularJs redirection link

Tags: angularjs

I have a small problem, when i run a visualforce page(called **QuizAngular**) with a angularjs code inside i get the following link `*****/apex/QuizAngular#/home`with a '#' added in the link which cause an error as '#' is not acceptable as avisualforce link. the problem is that i do not know why the '#' is here and i want to get rid of it ? 
here is the angularJs code that redirect the page when it first loads:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('quizApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
// Routing has been added to keep flexibility in mind. This will be used in future.
angular.module('quizApp')
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {

      var routes = [
          {
              url: '/home',
              template: 'templates/quiz.html',
              controller: 'quizCtrl'
          },
          {
              url: '/review',
              template: 'templates/review.html',
              controller: 'reviewCtrl'
          },
          {
              url: '/result',
              template: 'templates/result.html',
              controller: 'resultCtrl'
          },
          {
              url: '/create',
              template: 'templates/create.html',
              controller: 'createCtrl'
          }
      ];

      routes.forEach(function (r, index) {
          $routeProvider.when(r.url, { templateUrl: r.template, controller: r.controller });
      });
**//the redirection is set to /home without #, but it appears in the link**


      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
  }]);
```

i have posted a related [question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118139/how-to-run-an-angularjs-code-in-visualforce) if you want to understand fully my problem.

'

Comment: May you share the salesforce link?

Comment: Angular stays on a single Visualforce page but marks the location within the single page by adding a bookmark to the URL. (The original purpose of the bookmark was to jump to a particular point in the HTML page.) So `#/home` or `#/review` is what I would expect to be added to the URL. Can you explain in more detail what problem that causes: adding a bookmark to a Visualforce page in the browser's URL works fine for me. Links within your Angular partials just start at the `#` e.g. `href="#/review"`.

Comment: the problem is that getting an error: **Error: The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.** and i think that the '#' is the cause.

Comment: @itzmukeshy the complete link is https://c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular#/home

Comment: @MerabtiiBRAHIM i can't access it;

Comment: Exactly what piece of code is producing that error?

Comment: @itzmukeshy because i am working on the sandbox and site.com does not run in the sandbox so i can not make this Page accessible for you

Comment: here is the actual link **https://c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular#/home** but the right should be like that **https://c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular/home** without the **'#'** as the visualforce (I think) does not  authorize this '#' in the link and give this error ** Error: The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.**

Comment: the problem in n the redirection link in the angular js file and exactely here **$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });**. Angularjs adds a '#' before redirecting and i want to workarround this problem

Comment: Going to c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular#/home will recreate the angular app. Is that what you want? Usually you would make c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular when selected route in Angular to c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular#/home to start the app. Then links in the Angular app would then be `href="#/review"` i.e. within the single page you are already on.

Comment: No at all, i do not want to go to **c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular#/home** , i want to go to **c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular/home** without **'#'** that all, i thought that by adding the **  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });** code , i will get the root link which is **c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular** with **/home** at the end, **but** angularJs add a '#' to QuizAngular as the result is **c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/QuizAngular#/home**

Comment: Visualforce sees that as if you want to access a page called **QuizAngular#** so he returns an error because we can not use # in visualforce page name

Comment: So never put it in the name. Angular will add it.

Comment: @ Keith C i have no choice i have to run the page and then i will automatically redirected to home view in angularjs, it should be like that

Comment: So make the page name `QuizAngular` and link to that page and include an `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'})` page that defaults the app to the `QuizAngular#/home` URL when Angular initialises.